# Is it possible to replace 50N06 chip?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, identification, repair, damage

Problem:

I've got an LED light bar that has started blinking on half of it. I disassembled it and found an apparently damaged area on the PCB inside.

Question:

What is this chip? Would I have any hope of replacing it?

[image: Front of chip]

[image: Back of chip]

Comment: That's a MOSFET. However, there's probably more damage that caused it to die. The domed capacitor below it is probably the culprit.

Comment: @Unimportant I take it that's not how capacitors are supposed to look

Comment: The dome should be flat, that one's a goner. My best guess: insufficient power supply filtering due to that blown cap caused the MOSFET to spend a lot of time not fully turned on further causing it to get hot and die. Looks like the PCB is also cooked, from experience it looks like those pads are ready to come off along with the FET. U2 might've also taken a hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would I have any hope of replacing it?

The chip is just one of the possible problems. It may even have survived. The board material itself is toast.

A successful "repair" of this board entails reverse-engineering it, laying out a duplicate board, ordering it, then assembling it. This board is beyond "fixing": it has extensive thermal damage, and I would not trust it in the future even if, after replacing components, it happened to "work".

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor has a bulged top. It's most likely the culprit! It has lost its capacitance and the rest of the circuit tried to compensate until it overheated.

The MOSFET is only a symptom (and might not even be broken at all)..

BTW: It's almost always the electrolytic capacitors! They have liquid electrolyte inside and don't like heat. Good capacitors cost money so manufacturers cheap out there and get underspecced ones (small temperature range or not low ESR ones) because the device will run for some time anyway. It's also an easy way to limit the lifetime of a device.